# Set Inclusion Properties

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

Consider a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ converge almost surely to $X$. Define set $N:=\{\omega: X_n \to X \}^C$. Then it is claimed that we would have the following set inclusion properties.

$$
N^C \cap \{\omega: X \leq x-h\} \subset \liminf \{\omega: X_n\leq x\}\cap N^C \subset \limsup \{\omega: X_n\leq x\}\cap N^C \subset \{\omega: X\leq x\}\cap N^C.
$$

I can understand the second inclusion, but I do not get the **first** and the **last** one. Could anyone explain to me, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $h>0$.

For the **first**, we have

$$
\begin{align}
N^C\cap\{X\leqslant x-h\} &= N^C\cap\{\lim\sup X_n\leqslant x-h\}\ \subseteq\  N^C\cap\{\lim\sup X_n\leqslant x\} \\ &= N^C\cap\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}\{X_k\leqslant x\}\  =\  N^C\cap\lim\inf\{X_n\leqslant x\}
\end{align}
$$

So,

> $$
> N^C\cap\{X\leqslant x-h\}\  \subseteq\  N^C\cap\lim\inf\{X_n\leqslant x\}
> $$

And, for the **last**,

$$
\begin{align}
N^C\cap\lim\sup\{X_n\leqslant x\} &= N^C\cap\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{k\geqslant n}\{X_k\leqslant x\} \ \subseteq\  N^C\cap\{\lim\inf X_n\leqslant x\} \\&= N^C\cap\{X\leqslant x\}
\end{align}
$$

So,

> $$
> \begin{align}
> N^C\cap\lim\sup\{X_n\leqslant x\}\ \subseteq\   N^C\cap\{X\leqslant x\}
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you explain why we have $N^C\cap\{\lim\sup X_n\leqslant x\} = N^C\cap\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}\{X_k\leqslant x\}$, please?

Comment: For realisations of $X_n$ that converge to $X$, ... so think of each of these realisations as a converegent sequence of real numbers,... $\{\lim\sup X_n \leqslant x\}$ *iff* all but finitely many terms in the sequence either lie below, or are equal to, $x$. Another way to say it is that, eventually, each of the $X_n$ must either lie below or equal $x$.